# Petición post en reactjs con axios da error de envió de cabecera

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

Estoy haciendo una petición `axios.post()` y cuando voy a ver el resultado en consola me indica que tengo un error en la cabecera, mi código es el siguiente.

```
let axiosConfig = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};.
axios.post('http://serv.service', axiosConfig,{
  inCodLinea: "11",
  inUsrTransaccion: ""
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
```

y el error resultante es el siguiente:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://serv.service' from origin
>   'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Answer (score 1):

Esto se debe a que el backend alojado en **http://serv.service** esta bloqueando el acceso, lo que debes hacer es agregar desde el backend la cabecera para que le permita al frontend consultar información sin problemas

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Ya que no especificas en que lenguaje tienes hecho el backend no podría decirte que linea exactamente debes escribir, ni tampoco en que archivo, el mas común seria php

Si es php debes escribir la linea

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
```

Esto se debe ejecutar en la funcion o archivo central de tu aplicación, por ejemplo en un index.php

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente ya se encuentra esa linea de codigo en mi backend el cual es Nodejs, le he agregado una funcion, a parte de la que ya tenia y de igual forma, me sigue dando el mismo error, pareciera que no enviara el header.

esta es mi funcion en nodejs, cabe destacar que mi peticion no pasa por el nodejs no se si eso tenga algo que ver.

Comment: app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: '*/*' }));

// Configurar cabeceras y cors
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
});

Comment: app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
});